# objective-c method name in a protocol UIActionSheetDelegate

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking at a method

```
  -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

in the interface `UIActionSheetDelegate`. Is `actionSheet` a parameter name or part of method name???

Is the following a matching C declaration?

```
  (void) actionSheetdidDismissWithButtonIndex(UIActionSheet *actionSheet, NSInteger buttonIndex);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `actionSheet` a parameter name or part of method name???

Both.  The full method name is `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`, so "actionSheet" is part of that.  The parameters are `actionSheet` and `buttonIndex`.

> Is the following a matching C declaration?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

In the method `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` , there are 2 parameters. `actionSheet` & `buttonIndex`. A view controller might be delegate of multiple `actionSheets`, so first parameter tells about the `actionSheet` which triggered the method. Similarly, an `actionSheet` May contain multiple buttons, so 2nd parameter tells you, which button was pressed.

For this method:

```
 -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

This is the C equivalent:

```
(void) actionSheetdidDismissWithButtonIndex(UIActionSheet *actionSheet, NSInteger buttonIndex);
```